# How to access Guest (Linux) Filesystem from Host (Windows) in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, network-shares, windows, linux

I am trying to synchronize my music between my desktop (Ubuntu 9.10) and my laptop (VirtualBox: Windows 7 host & Ubuntu 9.10 guest) I use Unison to perform the actual sync, which itself is not the problem. I am ultimately trying to get my Windows 7 host to be able to access the music files so I can sync my iPod Touch.

What I need to figure out is how I can that to work. I would prefer to actually perform the sync to my Ubuntu Guest, mostly because of the filename allowed character differences between Windows and Linux.

Is there a way to access the files on my Linux Guest from the Windows Host?

- Can I mount the VDI in Windows when VirtualBox is off?
- Can I have Windows Host access the Linux Guest filesystem while VirtualBox is running?

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4748) forum post explains how to mount the disk with the machine switched off, but you will need to have it formatted with a Windows friendly filesystem...

I would use Samba to do a network share for access while the system is running, see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpSamba) page in for how to do it in Ubuntu. You could also use the "shared folders" thing in Virtualbox.

Comment: Yeah, I don't see why Windows sharing (smb) isn't used in this situation. It's relatively simple and fast.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I have had lots of issues with Samba.  If the amount of data fits, I would load up Dropbox or a similar service within Linux and the Windows Machine.

To Review your options if VBox guest is:

Samba (essentially share the folder on your network)
    Difficulty (hard, but only way if the music collection is larger than 20-30GB)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/281466/samba-how-can-i-access-a-share-on-a-virtualbox-guest-in-nat-mode

DropBox / Box / GDocs folder

if VBox is not running:

I think this depends on how the HD was made.  Neal's tip may help there.