# How to access server running in Virtualbox on Host machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to access samba on a guest Linux behind the VirtualBox NAT?](https://superuser.com/questions/104717/how-to-access-samba-on-a-guest-linux-behind-the-virtualbox-nat)

I have a VirtualBox running on a Win7 host with an Ubuntu guest. I have started a server in Ubuntu (Guest). How can I access it from the Host windows machine?

I assume I need to run this on a specific IP address, which I can expose to the Host as a LAN networked address?

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/104717/how-to-access-samba-on-a-guest-linux-behind-the-virtualbox-nat http://superuser.com/questions/105083/how-to-access-guest-linux-filesystem-from-host-windows-in-virtualbox

Comment: @Bobby: first yes (good catch, thanks), second no (it's about accessing the filesystem of a guest, eg directly, not the guest's network services)

Comment: @~quack: Whoops, you're right, that's swapped. :O

Answer (score 2):

if you have it set up in bridged mode if you know what ip the server has you should just be able to access it as you would a normal server using putty over ssh etc.