# Access Linux .vdi from Windows

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access Guest (Linux) Filesystem from Host (Windows) in VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/105083/how-to-access-guest-linux-filesystem-from-host-windows-in-virtualbox)

I have an Ubuntu Linux virtual machine on Windows, and I'd like to access and modify the guest file system from Windows. Is it possible to access and modify the guest filesystem from the host operating system (without booting the guest operating system)?

Comment: Yup, I would say it is

Comment: Yes. [This link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4748) link answers this question..

Comment: I hope this question's title won't be deleted when this question is merged - the alternate title might be beneficial to search engine users.